# node-vertica throws exception for multi-queries with a callback

Tags: node.js, vertica

I have created a simple web interface for vertica.
I expose simple operation above a vertica cluster.
one of the functionality I expose is querying vertica.
when my user enters a multi-query the node modul throws an exception and my process exits with exit 1.
Is there any way to catch this exception?
Is there any way overcome the problem in a different way?

Answer (score 2):

Right now there's no way to overcome this when using a callback for the query result.

Preventing this from happening would involve making sure there's only one query in the user's input. This is hard because it involves parsing SQL.

The callback API isn't built to deal with multi-queries. I simply haven't bothered implementing proper handling of this case, because this has never been an issue for me.

Instead of a callback, you could use the event listener API, which will send you lower level messages, and handle this yourself.

```
q = conn.query("SELECT...; SELECT...");
q.on("fields", function(fields) { ... });  // 1 time per query
q.on("row",    function(row) { ... });     // 0...* time per query
q.on("end",    function(status) { ... });  // 1 time per query
```